# Rendering child components without the parent component in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have simple react app that lists different shops from a mongodb database for example (HM, Amazon, Lindex etc) and displayed as cards with links (As seen in Boutique.js)

**Desired solution:**

I want so that each pressed card leads to a new page using router.

For example: If i press the card that is named "HM" then I want to be directed to /boutiques/HM that runs the Template component (as shown in Boutique.js) without parent component being rendered (except for the navbar)

The next card that is named "Amazon" should direct me to /boutiques/Amazon

The next card etc etc

**Current solution:**

My current solution renders the Template component under the cards whenever you click any of the cards. The cards are still visible in the page. I want so that the Template component renders without the parent showing (the cards). It should be just the navbar and a blank whitepage

**Question:**

How do I restructure my current solution to reach my desired solution?

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import "./CouponDeals.css";
import Boutiques from "./Boutiques";
import Home from './Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="main-container">
        <div className="navbar-section-container">
          <div class="navbar">
            <Link to="/">Hem</Link>
            <Link to="/boutiques">Butiker</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/boutiques/*" element={<Boutiques />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Boutiques.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "./Axios";
import Template from "./Template.js";

const Boutiques = () => {
  const [deals, setDeals] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const req = await axios.get("/butiker");
      setDeals(req.data);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="header-section">
        <h1 className="title">All Boutiques</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="card-section-container">
        <div className="deals-container">
          {deals.length > 0 ? (
            deals.map((deal, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="deal">
                <div className="button-container">
                  <Link to={`${deal.name}`} className="butiker-button">
                    <img src={deal.imgUrl} alt={deal.name} />
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p className="no-results">No results found</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        {deals.map((deal, index) => (
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={`${deal.name}`}
            element={<Template name={deal.name} />}
          />
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Boutiques;
```

Comment: Why don't just use two different routes? One is all-boutiques where you render your cards and other one is "boutiques/:name" where you render some exact boutique

Comment: As well, shouldn't the path and link to your template page be /boutique/deal.name? From what it looks like, right now the prefix boutique isn't there. of course, unless thats part of deal.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected boutique is showing below the cards because you implemented a router in the bottom `Boutiques.js`. Instead of using this approach you should try to add another dynamic `Route` in `App.js` that uses the name of the boutique as a parameter.

App.js

```
<Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/boutiques/" element={<Boutiques />} />
    <Route path="/boutiques/:name" element={<Template />} />
</Routes>
```

You will probably have to refactor your `Template` component so it retrieves the id of the boutique from the URL. You can do this like so:

`let { name } = useParams();`